# Confused on how to handle an I/O or blocking function in thread pool design

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix, threadpool

This is more a general design question so I apologize if this is not the correct location.

I am trying to move my current project implementation into a thread pool based design so I can control the order of execution better, and better manage resources.

I am working in C on a Linux/Unix based platform.

My current design at a high level:

- Logical execution objects create their own thread and `run` method

  - So they own the thread creation and execution
- I call these `tasks` but they are simply a function running on a thread
- There are three main type of tasks

  - I/O based tasks. So reading from a serial port, or a TCP socket, etc
  - Event based tasks. A new piece of data is added to a `queue`, thread is notified to wake up and do something
  - Control type tasks. These run at a predefined rate to either do some safety checks, or execute a function 20 times a second for example.

I would like to move this to a thread pool based design where the threads are allocated up front and work is “added”. But I am stuck on how to implement the I/O based tasks, and the control type tasks. The event based one is easy, on event add task to work queue

The only solutions I can see is

1. set up signals/alarms through the OS to ‘*notify*’ me when I/O is available but not sure what thread signals callbacks get called on.
2. Use OS timers, similar to signals for the control based tasks.

Is there a different approach or implementation technique that I can use? Or is signals/timers the best approach?

Comment: Look up **async I/O**. There are several different OS-level APIs that have been developed over the decades: select/poll, epoll, and now io_uring. It's a rabbit hole that goes insanely deep. The general idea is that you monitor multiple fds at the same time and your thread is notified whenever any of them is ready. Async I/O scales really well: one thread can service *thousands* of fds. No need for one-thread-per-fd. The tradeoff is it's  way more complex. Going from regular I/O to async often requires a near total rewrite of your entire program.

Comment: Let me know if you'd like an answer. I've only scratched the surface with my comment, but armed with these search terms you should be able to google to your heart's content.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I appreciate the insights, I was looking for the key terms and rabbit hole to go down. I am very early in the development of my application, so an architecture change is minimal at this point. But I could tell quickly that my ‘one thread per fd` was not looking good.